# How to do: when we press and hold, program just do once?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making a game console with C++, I have a problem. When I press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, my car in my game will jump. When I press and hold keyboard, my car will jump many times. I want: when I hold <kbd>SPACE</kbd> keyboard my car just jump once.

How to do this ?

I have read many topics about `GetAsyncKeyState()` but I don't know how to use it for my game.

```
  if ( _kbhit() )

 {

    char key = _getch();

    if ((key == 75) && (car.position.x > 2))
    {
        car.position.x -= 3;
    }
    else if ((key == 77) && (car.position.x < 24))
    {
        car.position.x += 3;
    }
    else if ((key == 32) && (car.position.y > 2))
    {
        car.position.y -= 5;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have described the desired and the observed behavior. This is excelent. But in order for your question to be answerable you need to show the code that you use to get the key. Standard C++ doesn't have this, so you are using some framework. We can't guess. Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState() is not a C++ function. Find out where you got that from and then please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: i can #include<Windows.h> and use it in C++ so I tag my question with C++

Comment: This is the first time i add a question on stackoverflow, i'm sorry

Comment: That's the Windows API then. I've given you a head start on formatting your question, remember to check the preview before posting :)

Comment: So welcome on SO! But as a new user, you really should read [ask]. Here you failed to select the relevant winapi tag (Quentin edited it for you), and you show no code forcing others to guess what your app contains. That's the reason why you were asked for a [mcve]. So you really, really should add code. Not the full code, but just enough to exhibit the problem.

Comment: I have add my code, but i hold key it do many time, i want: when i hold key it just do once

Comment: Please confirm your OS has a way to set key "delay to repeat" and "repeat interval".  (On Lubuntu, see preference->keyboard and mouse.)  You really will not want to change these settings.  I point this out only to inform you that the repeat-key concept is built into  OS-UI, and not something trivially dismissed.  AND, now that you know how keyboard repeats are generated, you can start thinking about how you might handle a "repeating-space-key-press",  that you want to represent a single key-press.  Perhaps you can figure out how to "dismiss-any-space-key-after-the-first-until...".  Good luck.

Comment: @2785528 can you give me some code for example ??? Thanks

Comment: Maybe.  I need to think about it, and try some things.  (I don't have a Windows, but Lubuntu might work well enough.)  Consider: use a thread to filter the keyboard input stream.  The filter would 'deliver' the 1st space char (and all other not-a-space char), but not any subsequent space chars UNTIL some other char is pressed (or maybe a kbhit or other timeout).

Comment: Research: You might consider curses, if available for your OS, but I don't remember this 'filter' idea.  You might review terminals 'modes', the terminals might have normal mode vs raw mode.  maybe raw mode might do something interesting.

Comment: What you really need is the key's repeat counter, but you don't get that with `_getch()` in a console app, but you do get with `WM_KEYDOWN` messages in a GUI app. So you may need to use a low-level keyboard hook via `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL)` to receive notifications of key presses and their repeat counts.

Answer (score 0):

Below I have an example software of one possible way to 'filter' duplicate space chars out of an input stream.

The idea relies on the use of two threads.

Thrd1 reads from a stringstream called ssIn.  (Replaced with cin in your code.)

Thrd1 (a filter) detects and discards back-to-back space chars, and only sends the first (of multiple space chars) to thrd2.

Thrd2 - reads from the single char buffer filled by thrd1 which will never see back-to-back space characters.

The 2 thrds are synchronized by a pair of semaphores (not mutex).

In my example, for my convenience, I used my version of a Posix semaphore.  I do not know if you have Posix, but I am confident you will easily find many example C++ semaphores available on the web, even within SO, and most using only C++ features.

---

Note that this is only 1 test ... the alphabet with 1,000,000 spaces injected after 'j'.  This is not a thourough test.  There probably will be other issues to deal with.  I have installed a harsh handling of input mis-behaviour.  The assert will help you identify the issues.

"thrd2" represents your toe-hold into this example.  Thrd2 receives the filtered stream.

---

```
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_chrono.hh"
using  namespace std::chrono_literals; // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30us
using  std::chrono::duration_cast;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::flush, std::endl;
//using std::cin;

#include <thread>
using  std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;

// Posix Process Semaphore, local mode, unnamed, unlocked
#ifndef                 DTB_PPLSEM_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_pplsem.hh"
using DTB::PPLSem_t;
#endif

// string ops
#ifndef                 DTB_SOPS_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_sops.hh"
using DTB::SOps_t;
#endif

#include <cassert>



namespace DTB
{
    class T946_t
   {
   public:
      int operator()(int argc, char* argv[]) // functor entry
         { return exec(argc, argv); }

   private:
      // uses compiler provided default ctor and dtor

      // Posix Process Semaphore, local mode (unnamed, unshared)
      // initial value unlocked
      PPLSem_t th1Sem;
      PPLSem_t th2Sem;
      char     kar = '\n';
      bool     done = false;
      size_t   m_rdy;

      thread*   th1;
      string th1Log;

      thread*   th2;
      string th2Log;

      stringstream ssIn; // debug - replaces cin

      stringstream ss1DR; // th1 delay'd report
      stringstream ss2DR; // th2 delay'd report

      // utilities
      SOps_t    sops;  // string ops - digiComma

      int exec(int , char** )
         {
            // test init: insert a possible user input into ssIn
            init_ssIn();

            int retVal = 0;
            Time_t start_ns = HRClk_t::now();

            th1Sem.lock();  // block until threads are ready
            th2Sem.lock();  // block

            // start ---------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            th1 = new thread(&T946_t::thrd1, this);
            assert(nullptr != th1);
            while (0 == (m_rdy & 0x01))
               std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);

            // start ---------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            th2 = new thread(&T946_t::thrd2, this);
            assert(nullptr != th2);
            while (0 == (m_rdy & 0x02))
               std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);

            th1Sem.unlock();

            // spin wait for threads to complete
            while (!done)
            {
               std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
            }

            th1->join();
            th2->join();
            cout << "\n  join()'s complete";

            auto  duration_ns = duration_cast<NS_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_ns).count();

            cout << "\n  T901_t::exec() duration   "
                 << sops.digiComma(duration_ns) << " ns" << endl;

            // output the delay'd reports
            cout << ss1DR.str() << ss2DR.str() << endl;

            return retVal;
         }

      void init_ssIn()
         {
            ssIn << "abcdefghij";
            for (int i=0; i<1000001; ++i)   ssIn << ' ';
            std::string::size_type k =  ssIn.str().size();
            ssIn << "klmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            //                                          a..j
            cout << "\n  ssIn: '"  << ssIn.str().substr(0, 10)
                 << " ...spaces... " << ssIn.str().substr(k, 16) << "'"
                 << "\n  ssIn.str().size(): "
                 << sops.digiComma(ssIn.str().size()) << endl;
         }

      void thrd1()
         {
            uint64_t th1Count  = 0;
            uint64_t th1Skips  = 0;
            char lkar      = '\0';
            m_rdy |= 0x01;    // sync msg to main

            do {

               getNextKar(lkar); // read from input (ssIn or cin)

               th1Sem.lock();  // wait for thrd2 to give permission
               {
                  if(' ' == lkar)   // current input kar
                  {
                     if(' ' == kar) // previous kar
                     {
                        // filter out back-to-back space chars
                        th1Skips += 1;
                        th1Sem.unlock(); // skip the handshake, no char to send,
                        //                  give self permission-to-proceed
                        continue;
                     }
                  }

                  // else, not a duplicate space
                  th1Count += 1;
                  kar       = lkar; // write to input of thrd2
                  th1Log   += lkar; // log
                  lkar      = ' ';
               }
               th2Sem.unlock(); // give thrd2 permission-to-proceed

               if (ssIn.eof())
               {
                  done = true;
                  break;
               }

            }while(!done);

            ss1DR
               << "\n  th1Count    "  << sops.digiComma(th1Count)
               << "\n  th1Skips    "  << sops.digiComma(th1Skips)
               << "\n  th1Log      "  << th1Log
               << "\n  thrd1 exit  "  << endl;
         }


      // read from ssIn for development
      // read from cin for app
      void getNextKar(char& lkar)
         {
            // ssIn >> lkar; // reads 1 char, but skips multiple blank chars
            // lkar = ssIn.get(); returns an integer (not a char)
            (void)ssIn.get (lkar);

            if(ssIn.fail())
            {
               if(ssIn.eof()) return; // not a fail
               assert(0);             // harsh exit, might want something gentler
            }
         }


      void thrd2()
         {
            uint64_t th2Count = 0;
            m_rdy |= 0x02;    // sync msg to main

            do {
               th2Sem.lock();    // wait for thrd1 to give permission
               char t = kar;
               th1Sem.unlock();  // give permission-to-proceed to thrd1

               // simulate application - no duplicate spaces from input
               th2Log   += t;
               th2Count += 1;
               // end of sim

            }while(!done);

            ss2DR
               << "\n  th2Count   " << sops.digiComma(th2Count)
               << "\n  th2Log     " << th2Log
               << "\n  thrd2 exit " << endl;
         }

   }; // class T946_t

} // namespace DTB


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { return DTB::T946_t()(argc, argv); }
```

The output looks like:

```
  ssIn: 'abcdefghij ...spaces... klmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  ssIn.str().size(): 1,000,027

  join()'s complete
  T901_t::exec() duration   120,421,582 ns

  th1Count    28
  th1Skips    1,000,000
  th1Log      abcdefghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz 
  thrd1 exit  

  th2Count   28
  th2Log     abcdefghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz 
  thrd2 exit
```

The duration is 120 ms for 1 Million chars input.

Comment: It's a cute idea, but the OP really just wants to disable key-repeat. It doesn't even need to be cross-platform. No need for all that post-processing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As @Remy Lebeau pointed out you can get the repeat count by install [WH_KEYBOARD hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_keyboard) and filter the key held pressed in [KeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Of course, for simple, no need install a hook you can filter repeat [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-keydown) messages in [window procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-window-procedures) when you press the space key and hold. The following is an example you can refer to:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if (wParam == VK_SPACE)
    {           
        if (!((HIWORD(lParam) & 0x4000) || (HIWORD(lParam) & 0x8000)))
        {
            isKeyHold = TRUE; // First time pressed
            OutputDebugString(TEXT("pressed !\n")); 
        }
        else if (isKeyHold && (HIWORD(lParam) & 0x4000))
        {
            OutputDebugString(TEXT("hold !\n")); 
            return 1; // Don't handle the message when the key is pressed and held.
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_KEYUP:
    if (wParam == VK_SPACE && isKeyHold)
    {
        isKeyHold = FALSE; // Clear the isKeyHold flag when release the key.
        OutputDebugString(TEXT("release !\n"));
    }
    break;
```